# Change total input value according to dynamic radio input attribute values with jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Need help with adding, removing, changing the values of `data-dynamic` attribute of radio input elements from the total input value.

**Dynamic generated radio inputs**

```
<input type="radio" id="valetId" name="valetId" value="0" data-dynamic="0" />
<input type="radio" id="valetId" name="valetId" value="1" data-dynamic="20" />
<input type="radio" id="valetId" name="valetId" value="2" data-dynamic="40" />
```

and the total input is:

```
<input type="text" id="Total" name="Total" class="form-control" value="" />
```

So far I have the jQuery script, that adds the radio input `data-dynamic` values to total

```
  $("input[type=radio]").click(function(event) {
    //alert('Button pressed with value: '+dynamicValue);
        $("input[type=radio]:checked").each(function() {
            total = Number($('#Total').val()) + $(this).data('dynamic');
        });
    $('#Total').val(total);
  });
```

I need help with how to remove the checked radio input `data-dynamic` attribute from the total,  add the 2nd radio input `data-dynamic` attribute if checked or reset the total input value to original price if radio input `data-dynamic` attribute with 0 is checked.

Thanks.

Comment: You mean if it is check: add, if it is not: substract?

Comment: no the price added to total according to checked input and if input with zero value checked total rest to original price

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `change` event which is only called when you check a radio. (it will not fire when unchecked, so that you don't need to substract)
Then you don't have to loop through all the radios, but just grab the value of the radio which has been checked.

```
var total, myVal;
$("input[type=radio]").change(function(event) {
    // check if 'myVal' variable is defined, if not, set it to the input field value (or 0 if it's empty):
    if(myVal === undefined){
       myVal = ( parseInt($('#Total').val()) || 0);
    }
    total = myVal + parseInt($(this).attr('data-dynamic'));
    $('#Total').val(total);
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/v015pgvw/)

---

**EDIT**

If the input field initial `value` can be updated manualy (by typing in), you could use this. It will only grab the input field value when it was updated **not** using check-boxes:

```
var inputVal, prevData, total = $('#Total');
$("input[type=radio]").change(function() {
    var dynamicData = parseInt($(this).attr('data-dynamic')),
        totalVal = parseInt(total.val());
    if(inputVal === undefined || totalVal !== prevData + inputVal){
        inputVal = (totalVal || 0);
    }
    total.val(inputVal + (prevData = dynamicData));
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/gy1c2236/)

---

Make sure that all of your radios have **unique** `id` attribute.

Comment: Thanks alot, it worked, I made little changes in the script and replace "parseInt" with "parseFloat" so values like 1.99 will add with .99

Comment: @shehary , glad I could help :) . You can look at **EDIT** section, If your input field initial value can be updated manualy.

Comment: you just saved me alot of time, the edited script is the next step i was gona work on, many many thanks again.