# add value to total if radio box checked

Tags: javascript, jquery

There is something not working at this script.
I need when check one radio button to add the amount at the total price.
This is doing well, but if I check different radio buttons, it ads all of them.
If I have total = 100$; and button1=10$, button2=10$, button3=10$
and if I check all 3... I will get total = 130$ instead of 110$

```
function calculateTotal(payment)
{
    var check=document.getElementById("check").value;
    var city = document.getElementsByName('loc');
    var value= payment.value;
    var total= document.getElementById("totl").value;
    var tcharge;
    var pvcharge=document.getElementById("ch").value;
    if(value==0 && check==0)
    return;

    if(value==0 && check==1)
    {
        total= parseFloat(parseFloat(total)-parseFloat(pvcharge)).toFixed(2);
        tcharge=0;
    }else
    {
    if(total>=200)
    return;
    if(value=='online' || value =='transfer_bancar' || value=='cash' || value == 'la_sediul_nostru')
        {
            if(city[0].checked)
            {
            total= parseFloat(parseFloat(total)+15.0).toFixed(2);
            tcharge=15.00;
            }
            else
            if(city[1].checked)
            {
            total= parseFloat(parseFloat(total)+30.0).toFixed(2);
            tcharge=30.00;
            }
        }
        else
        if(value='la_expeditor')
        {

        if(city[0].checked)
            {
            total= parseFloat(parseFloat(total)+30.0).toFixed(2);
            tcharge=30.00;
            }
            else
            if(city[1].checked)
            {
            total= parseFloat(parseFloat(total)+60.0).toFixed(2);
            tcharge=60.00;
            }
        }
        }

        document.getElementById("tot").innerHTML=total+" LEI";
        document.getElementById("totl").value=total;
        document.getElementById("amt").value=total;
        document.getElementById("tcharge").innerHTML=tcharge+" LEI";
        document.getElementById("check").value=1;
        document.getElementById("ch").value=tcharge;

}
```

radio box

```
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="radio" name="payment" value="online" id="online" onClick="calculateTotal(this); return empty();" /> <span class="fontext"><b>asdadasdad</b></span></td>                
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="radio" name="payment"  value="transfer_bancar" id="bancar" onClick="calculateTotal(this); return bancarval();" /> <span class="fontext"><b>asdadadadasd</b></span></td>                
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="radio" name="payment"  value="cash" onClick="calculateTotal(this);return empty();" /> <span class="fontext"><b>asdadadadadad</b></span></td>                
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="radio" name="payment" value="la_expeditor" onClick="calculateTotal(this); return empty();" /> <span class="fontext"><b>asdadasdadad</span></td>        </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="radio" name="payment" value="la_sediul_nostru" onClick="calculateTotal(this); return empty();" /> <span class="fontext"><b>asdadasdad</b></span></td>                
    </tr>
   <tr>
   <tr>
        <td colspan="2">&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="radio" name="payment" value="0" onClick="calculateTotal(this); return empty();" /> <span class="fontext"><b>asdasdasd</b></span></td>        </tr>
   <tr>
        <td><span class="fontext"><b>Cost transport: </b></span></td> <td><span class="fontext" ><b id="tcharge">0.00 LEI</b></span></td>       </tr>
```

and php

```
if($Tott<200)
if(isset($_POST['loc']))
{
$tcharges=$_POST['loc'];

        if(isset($_POST['payment']))
        {
            $payment=$_POST['payment'];
            if($payment!=0)
          if($payment=='online' || $payment =='transfer_bancar' || $payment=='cash' || $payment == 'la_sediul_nostru')
            {
                if($tcharges=='in')
                    $Tott+=15;
                    else
                    $Tott+=30;
            }else
            if($payment=='la_expeditor') 
            {
                if($tcharges=='in')
                    $Tott+=30;
                    else
                    $Tott+=60;

            }


        }
}
```

Comment: Please post the associated HTML so we can troubleshoot.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change total input value according to dynamic radio input attribute values with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28993670/change-total-input-value-according-to-dynamic-radio-input-attribute-values-with) (since there's a jQuery tag)

Comment: How can you check all 3 radio buttons? Only one button in a set can be checked.

Comment: @BenjaminRay I edited full code

Answer (score 0):

Each time, you're operating off the total of the previous calculation.

Offending line:

```
    var total= document.getElementById("totl").value;
```

Instead, change it to operate off the original, clean value.

Comment: can you please wrote line? I tried to set var totalu= document.getElementById("totl").value; and use total= parseFloat(parseFloat(totalu)+15.0).toFixed(2);

Comment: $Tott += $Ret['p_price'];
<?php echo number_format($Tott, 2, '.', ' '); ?>